# Wifi detecting but not connecting

Tags: 14.04, networking, wireless

I just installed Ubuntu 14.04 LTS. I am able to see the wifi but not able to connect to it. It keeps asking for my password again and again.

I am able to connect to my phones hotspot and and other USB wifi dongle such as MTS as well.

Other people who have recently installed ubuntu 14.04 while i did are able to connect to that particular wifi but not me.

I couldnot check to see if it works with other routers other than mine coz theres no other open network near by.

Friend of mine who is able to connect to the wifi has a sony e series
I have a dell xps15 L502x.

Comment: What is the wifi device `lshw -c net` in terminal and add the result to your question

Comment: Make it `LANG=C lshw -c net`

Comment: Tried restarting the router ?

Answer (score 0):

I have a similar problem with my Lenovo, on both the wifi and the ethernet connection here is the result of the comment you've asked:

```
  *-network               
       description: Ethernet interface
       product: Ethernet Connection I217-LM
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 19
       bus info: pci@0000:00:19.0
       logical name: eth0
       version: 04
       serial: 04:da:d2:bf:2c:ac
       capacity: 1Gbit/s
       width: 32 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
       configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=e1000e driverversion=2.3.2-k firmware=0.13-3 latency=0 link=no multicast=yes port=twisted pair
       resources: irq:45 memory:b2a00000-b2a1ffff memory:b2a3f000-b2a3ffff ioport:5080(size=32)
  *-network
       description: Wireless interface
       product: Wireless 7260
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:03:00.0
       logical name: wlan0
       version: 83
       serial: 5c:51:4f:9e:a1:c9
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=iwlwifi driverversion=3.13.0-74-generic firmware=22.24.8.0 ip=192.168.1.12 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11abgn
       resources: irq:47 memory:b2800000-b2801fff
```

I tried restarting the computer, stopping it, removing the battery then restarting it, I tried restarting the box as well.